# How do I share styles in WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

There's no "ResourceDictionary" templates in the WP7 SDK. Is there a different way of creating styles to share across pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App.xaml` is the starting point where you can create various styles - specifically in `Application.Resources`.

And what do you mean by:

> There's no "ResourceDictionary"
>   templates in the WP7 SDK

What's wrong with using `ResourceDictionary` directly in `App.xaml`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use to share it

```
    <!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="bestButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
...
```

Or page resouces to limit the scope

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
            <Storyboard  x:Name="historyAnimationIn">
```